# Create new raster using 'if statement' in R

Tags: r, gis, raster

I would like to create a new raster in R based on values of another raster. I can do this in ArcGIS using the CON tool but I can't seem to find a way in R. Below is what I have done:

```
r<-raster("b1.tif")
if (r>33){
r2<-200
}else{
r2<--0.156*r^2 + 11.2*r + 0.1
}
```

The above is returning the error:

```
Error in if (slp > 33) { : argument is not interpretable as logical
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: what are you going to do with r>33 ? You are comparing apples with bananas. r is an object of class "rasterLayer" and 33 is an integer.

Answer (score 0):

`r < 33` does not work because you are comparing an object of class "rasterLayer" with an integer. You have to compare a value(like max) of the tiff.

```
r <- raster("b1.tif")
if (r@data@max > 33){
  r2 <- 200
}else{
  r2 <-- 0.156*r^2 + 11.2*r + 0.1
}
```

If you want to access all the values of the tiff do: `r@data@values`
Depending on this values you can create you second tiff.
If you want to copy the whole tiff just do : `r <- r2`

Comment: I've tries this

Comment: I tried this but I get an error 'missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed' and another 'the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used.

Comment: pls explain more accurate what you wanna do, that i can help.. What do you want to compare with 33 ?